# Exporting a QBO3 table to Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, xslt, qbo3

I need to generate an excel spreadsheet populated from a table within a custom form. What is the appropriate method to perform this action? I see that existing panels sometimes contain an option that calls "qbo3.getObject(this).download({DisplaySize: 0, Batch: 1000000});", but this does not apply to my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QBO3's base HttpHandler supports an `&Output=Excel` method, which will deliver any DataSet or DataReader as a native .xslx via via MS OpenXml code. The pattern is:

```
{HttpHandler}/{Operation}?{Parameters}&Output=Excel
```

For example:

```
Loan.ashx/MyCustomList?SqlFilter=ActiveOnly&Output=Excel
```